# Извлечь данные из json и обработать

Tags: php

Пытаюсь собрать массив данных по трем критериям "city","country", "region".
Принцип работы таков: считать IP пользователя и подставить его в json, после спарсить 2 значения ("city","country" (регион недоступен))  Но мой код ругается на array_merge. Подскажите, как мне это сделать?

```
public static function GEO()
{
    $ip = Route::clientIp();
    $json = file_get_contents('http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/'.$ip);
    var_dump($json);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    $loc = [
        'city' => null, 
        'country' => null,
        'region' => null
    ];

    $location = array_merge($loc, $data);
    return $location;

}
```

Comment: Получилось спарсить "city", но если парсить страну, то отображается это "a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Russia";s:4:"code";s:2:"RU";}" , как достать "name" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public static function GEO()
{
    $ip = Route::clientIp();
    $json = file_get_contents('http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/'.$ip);
    var_dump($json);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    $location = [
        'city' => null, 
        'country' => null,
        'region' => null
    ];

    $location['city'] = $data['city']
    $location['country'] = $data['country']['name']
    return $location;

}
```

Или еще проще:

```
public static function GEO()
{
    $ip = Route::clientIp();
    $json = file_get_contents('http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/'.$ip);
    var_dump($json);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    return  [
        'city' => $data['city'], 
        'country' => $data['country']['name'],
        'region' => null
    ];



}
```

Дело в том, что `$data['country']` содержит не значение, а еще один массив:

```
"name"=>"Russia",
"code"=>"RU"
```

Поэтому, чтобы добраться до `name`, нужно взять элемент массива внутри массива:

```
$data['country']['name']
```

Comment: А мне нужно использовать этот код  $location = array_merge($loc, $data);
        return $location;?  Так же вылез нотис " Notice: Array to string conversion"

Comment: Не совсем понимаю... Я же все правильно делаю?  public static function GEO()
    {
  $ip = Route::clientIp();
  $json = file_get_contents('http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/'.$ip);
  $data = json_decode($json, true);

        $loc = [
            'city' => null, 
            'country' => null,
            'region' => null
        ];
  
  $loc['city'] = $data['city'];
  $loc['country'] = $data['country']['name'];
  
        $location = array_merge($loc, $data);
        return $location;
    }

Comment: @Елизавета, изменил ответ

Comment: Вы не могли бы прислать готовый метод, а то я совсем запуталась(

Comment: @Елизавета, изменил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!